# How can i generate pdf reports using symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I have created an examanition module which provides the report card to the user as an HTML (twig) format. Now I want the user should be able to save the report card as pdf. I have added a button as Save ReportCard and I want to write the code in my controller to generate this pdf file with same content as of the html. I googled and found these links:

1. [PDF Lib 8](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-8/)
2. [Generate PDFs with PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-pdfs-php/)

These links where great but I couldnt get how can i use them in symfony2. I am new to symfony2 and Php. Can anyonw help me here with the same.

Answer (score 14):

Another solution, which is more painless than create a whole custom PDF, would be to create a print css. then get the whole DOM with a lib like wkhtml2pdf. There is also a Lib from knplabs https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy and the bundle https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

i often use this for tricky html5 projects. with the javascript support from wkhtml2pdf you can add svg's and other pretty things to your pdf...

Comment: The KNP Snappy Bundle is the way to go for your particular problem. I'm doing exactly the same thing with them in my application.

Answer (score 6):

A great library with a lot of features is [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).
WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle or IoTcpdfBundle are some bundles created by community based in that library.
You can find some bundles that help you to create PDFs at [knpbundles](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=pdf).

Answer (score 4):

I have spent many hours in search for appropriate library. The primary goal was to generate PDF as easily as possible **without** coordinate positioning, special functions for line-feed and what not...

The best match I found so far was: https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle

... which has Symfony bundle and GitHub entry contains tons of examples. Excellent library.

Comment: Hello, can you tell me where are all those examples you mention? Thanks a lot